# positioning a span within a li

Tags: html, css

ive got a list set up with a background image set to the left of each of the lines of text
although they dont seem to line up, i put a span around the text to try and reposition the text but it didnt seem to work

heres the code im using..

HTML

```
<ul class="price-features">
<li><span>One page website with contact form</span></li>
<li><span>Social Media Integration</span></li>
<li><span>One year hosting + Domain registration</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
 .price-features{
margin-top:30px;
 }

 .price-features li{
background-image:url(/images/prices/orange-arrow.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left;
padding-left:15px;
height:30px;
border-bottom:#999 1px solid;
background-color:#996;
 }

 .price-features li span{
  padding-top:5px;
 }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV1LM.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Padding only affects block-level elements. You'll need to either change your `span` to be a block-level element or override the default `display` to be `block` or `inline-block`.

```
.price-features li span{
  display: block;
  padding-top:5px;
}
```